# how to create test class for trigger

Tags: apex

```
trigger UpdateTrigger on Contract (after update)
{
    //system.debug('In Trigger');
    // List of accounts to update or insert (Bulk)
    Boolean IsRetention = false;
    Set<ID> SetContractId = new set<ID>();

Map<string,contentworkspace> MapContractSBGtolibrary = new Map<string,contentworkspace>();
set<string> SetofcontractSBG = new set<string>();
set<id> setCDids = new set<id>();
List<contentversion> ListCV = new List<contentversion>();
Map<id,set<id>> mapCDidtocVid = new Map<id,set<id>>();
List<contentdocument> listofCDtoupdate = new  List<contentdocument>();
Map<id,contentdocument> mapCD;
Map<string,id> MapofCWS = new Map<string,id>();
  Map<string,string> MapSBGtoName = new   Map<string,string>();


// 1>?? -- contract--sbg--cws

for(Contract Cnt : Trigger.new){
    if (Cnt.Retention__c != 'Delete'){
        IsRetention = true;
        SetContractId.add(Cnt.id);
        SetofcontractSBG.add(Cnt.Contract_SBG__C);
    }
  // system.debug('SetofcontractSBG>>>>>>>>>>>>>' +SetofcontractSBG);
}
 for(contract con : [Select id,contract_SBG__c,(select id,contentdocumentid,contract__c,contract__r.contract_SBG__c from Content_Versions__r) from contract where id in : SetContractId]){

         for(contentversion cv1 : con.Content_Versions__r){
              ListCV.add(cv1);
              setCDids.add(cv1.contentdocumentid);
         }
      system.debug('setCDids>>>>>>>>>>>>>' +setCDids);


 }
 set<string> setLibraryname= new set<string>();
 string lib1 = label.ACS;
 for(string sbg : SetofcontractSBG){
     if(sbg == 'ACS'){
         MapSBGtoName.put(sbg,label.Contract_ACS_SBG);
         setLibraryname.add(label.Contract_ACS_SBG);
     }
     else if(sbg == 'AERO'){
         MapSBGtoName.put(sbg,label.Contract_AERO_SBG);
         setLibraryname.add(label.Contract_AERO_SBG);
     }
     else if(sbg == 'TS'){
         MapSBGtoName.put(sbg,label.Contract_TS_SBG);
         setLibraryname.add(label.Contract_TS_SBG);
     }
     else if(sbg == 'CORP'){
         MapSBGtoName.put(sbg,label.Contract_CORP_SBG);
         setLibraryname.add(label.Contract_CORP_SBG);
     }
     else if(sbg == 'PMT'){
         MapSBGtoName.put(sbg,label.Contract_PMT_SBG);
         setLibraryname.add(label.Contract_PMT_SBG);
     }

 }

      //system.debug('setLibraryname>>>>>>>>>>>>>' +setLibraryname);

 for(contentworkspace cws : [Select Id, name from ContentWorkSpace where name in : setLibraryname ]){
    {
        MapofCWS.put(cws.name,cws.id); 
    }
 }
 mapCD = new map<id,contentdocument>([select id, parentid from contentdocument where id in: setCDids]);

 //system.debug('mapCD >>>>>>>>>>>>>' +mapCD );

 for(contentversion cv : ListCV){
     if(mapCD.containskey(cv.contentdocumentId)){

         mapCD.get(cv.contentdocumentid).Parentid = mapofCWS.get(MapSBGtoName.get(cv.contract__r.contract_SBG__c));

         listofCDtoupdate.add(mapCD.get(cv.contentdocumentId));    

     }

 }
 if(listofCDtoupdate.size() > 0){
     update listofCDtoupdate;
    // system.debug('listofCDtoupdate>>>>>>>>>>>>>' +listofCDtoupdate);
 }
```

Comment: Give us a Snippet of code which you are not able to get coverage for ?  Screenshot from Developer console will help a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following - it will cover at leat 60 - to - 75% of your code. 
And let me know which part of the code is not covered yet !

@isTest
    private class MyTestClass{
        static testMethod void runPositiveTestCases() {

```
        Contact objCon = new Contact();
        objCon.Retention__c ='ValueExcept_Delete";
        objCon.Contract_SBG__C = 'ACS';
        //all other required fields
        insert objCon;

        Content_Versions__c objCV = new Content_Versions__c();
        objCV.contentdocumentid ='Value'; //related ID
        objCV.contract__c = objCon.id;
        // all other required fields
        insert objCV;
}
}
```